# IE11 renders page incorrectly in an inactive tab

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, internet-explorer-11

The problem is I try to render an iframe with some another page inside of it.

The code looks a bit like this:

```
<div>
  <iframe></iframe>
</div>
```

The outer div is abolutely positioned and has width and height. The iframe and div are created dynamically.
The problem is inner html tag's top, when it's rendered, positioned above the iframe top, making all inner content to render incorrectly. And it is positioned static and have no css rules that could possibly move it to the top. Or sometimes it could be only the inner content, in the body, or the upper rendered div inside of it, on the second nesting level, while the other elements on the above levels being rendered correctly.

This issue reproduces in IE only (I'm not sure if this is 11th version only) and only when you you have some other tab selected while it loads in another, inactive tab.

I also couldn't reproduce this issue in JSFiddle or anywhere else by having some similar constructs. And I can't give real code from the production enviroment.

I know, it is crazy to ask people to help with such lack of information, but I hope, someone had the same issue and knows how to solve it, because I'm really out of ideas.

Does anyone know how this issue could possibly be solved?

Comment: Did you try to build a MWE using a single html page and replicating part of the CSS?

Comment: @Seth Yes, I tried. Unfortunately, that didn't help, I think it's missing something important, but I don't know what exactly. My examples worked fine.